# How to handle an aggregated list of the fields of multiple objects?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, class-design

I have some objects each hold a list of variables, and a list which holds all variables of these objects, for example

```
class A
{
   List<Var> varList;
}

class B
{
   List<A>   aList;
   List<Var>   allVarOfAs; 
  // it is a common list which holds the members of varList of all members of the aList
}
```

Now if an object from `varList` in an an object of `aList` (an `A` object in `B`) is removed, how can I update the common list `allVarOfAs`?

What is the pattern for such situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to NOT have the aggregated list '`allVarOfAs`'. Instead make it a method or property which returns the aggregated list on the fly, but doing a `SelectMany` over `aList`. E.g.

```
IEnumerable<Var> allVarOfAs 
{
     get
     {
          return aList.SelectMany(a=>a.varList);
     }
}
```

or

```
List<Var> allVarOfAs
{
     get
     {
          return aList.SelectMany(a=>a.varList).ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be the `get` function of a `allVarOfAs` property.

Answer (score 0):

First, add some encapsulation and suppose you declare your fields private and define public `add` and `remove` methods in class `B` (which add and remove `A` instances). Then, `add` and `remove` will be respondible for updating `allVarOfAs`.

The problem with this approach is that as long as any *other* object has a reference to the same `aList` (directly, or by having a reference to an `A`), it can modify it without going throught your `B` instance. You would have to ensure that no instance of class `A` is ever shared with other objects, and that `A.varList` is only modified by a `B` object (otherwise, the actual union of lists and the one computed in `B` could differ).

It is simpler and always correct to recompute `allVarOfAs` when needed (see [JacquesB's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285495/33157)).

Maintaining `allVarOfAs` *could* be done incrementally: but do you really need to?

Comment: I think the main problem is that `varList` might be modified in an instance of `A` class. Even private, the functions inside it can modify the `varList` without notifying the `B` object.